# Will a higher open-circuit voltage decrease the short-circuit current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I don't know anymore if I read it somewhere or (mis)read it between the lines in a paper... so I would like to know if there is such a relationship between the open-circuit voltage $V_{OC}$ and the short-circuit current $I_{SC}$ ?

Comment: Why should there be such a relationship?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Jon Custer, well, why the VOC increases with Eg, whereas ISC decreases, could be explained this way: With higher Eg more energy is needed to excite an electron-hole pair, so this will limit the current, but the VOC is measured under forward bias condition, where the external electric field diminishes the potential barrier across the junction more than the higher Eg increases it.

Comment: The Photon, as I said, "I don't know anymore if I read it somewhere or (mis)read it between the lines in a paper."

Comment: Qmechanic, which acronyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relationship between the open circuit voltage and short circuit current. It’s called the Thevenin resistance $R_{Thev}$ where

$$R_{Thev}=\frac{V_{OC}}{I_{SC}}$$

Where $V_{OC}$ is the open circuit voltage and $I_{SC}$ is short circuit current.

But a higher open circuit voltage for the same source resistance will give you an increase in short circuit current, not a decrease.

Hope this helps

Comment: Notice the "solar-cells" tag on the question. Is there a reason to think that solar cells have constant thevenin resistance when their design is changed or illumination is changed (asking because I don't actually know)?

Comment: @The Photon Neither do I. I took the OP question as a generic circuit theory question not a specific solar cell question

Comment: Solar cell is my context of asking the question (since there the terms VOC and ISC are very common), but I guess the Thévenin's theorem also applies here... although I am not sure.. thanks for hinting me to this theorem!

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions Ok, in that case, you might find the following helpful,  re: applicability of Thevenin's theorem to solar cell circuits. https://sinovoltaics.com/solar-basics/thevenins-theorem-and-solar-pv-modules/

Comment: I don't understand in this article how it is explained that a "slow solar cell" (with less current) will "slow down" all others.... :/

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions What article are you referring to? I don't see it in this article.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I confused it with series circuits where one solar cell with less current (due to shading for example) will cause all other solar cells in the circuit to have the same current (because of the continuity equation). I somehow thought that this relates as well to Thévenin's theorem...